# Is there a way to create a modeless dialog in an Angular/Electron app?

Tags: angular, angular-material, dialog, electron, modeless-dialog

Is there a way to create a modeless dialog in an Angular/Electron app?

I'm looking at the samples below, and they're all modal:

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

I need to be able to open multiple windows at the same time and move them around. But I could not find any samples for that.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT 1:**

I've tried the following, but it's somehow leading me to the default page, index.html:

```
window.open('/app/shared/settings/user-preferences.html');
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

I've also tried the following, but it's not compiling.

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron'); //does not compile!!?
let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
win.on('closed', () => {
  win = null;
});

win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/shared/settings/user-preferences.html`);
```

But that does not compile and gives me the error message:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\projects\...\MyApp\node_modules\electron'
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\projects\...\MyApp\node_modules\electron'
```

Comment: Hi, you mean in something like [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) ? as in an acutal new window with dialog context...

Comment: Thank you for the response. window.open() might do. I've tried it, but it somehow leads to Index.html. Am I using it correctly with this? window.open('/app/shared/settings/user-preferences.html');

Comment: check post if it's what you looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) API in order to open a new window instance of a window by providing an URL like so and use dialog context in it:

```
window.open('https://www.angular.io', 'nameOfWindow');
```

Here's a working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-new-window-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnew-window-button%2Fnew-window-button.component.ts)

**EDIT1:**

In consideration to [electron API](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open#using-chromes-windowopen-implementation) setups you also need to do following:

> If you want to use Chrome's built-in window.open() implementation, set nativeWindowOpen to true in the webPreferences options object.

**EDIT2:**

In consideration to a local file you can do this:

```
window.open(`file://${__dirname}/app/shared/settings/user-preferences.html`, 'nameOfWindow')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This, unfortunately, is not what I was after. I am running an Electron app for Desktop, not a website. So I would need a way to open a local file, similar to this: window.open('/app/shared/settings/user-preferences.html');

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It still doesn't work. It's opening a blank HTML screen with blank head and blank body. I also tried renaming the file to index.html, but it still wouldn't work.

Comment: have you logged the filepath of EDIT2 and comparing it with where it's really located as it might be path issue?

Comment: Pretty sure I did. Although I'm not entirely sure how that relates to the {__direname} path. I've tried another file located in:
C:\Projects\TestApp\src\components\share\share-file-dialog\share-file-dialog.component.html
... And the code I got so far is:
window.open(`file://${__dirname}/src/components/share/share-file-dialog/share-file-dialog.component.html`, 'TestSettings123');